# HTML Request from Denticon

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am attempting to query a cloud database using the requests package. This is from Denticon, a dentistry software that my office uses to schedule patients and store information on the cloud about them and their dental history. Eventually, I would like to process and analyze the results of the query in pandas but I am having issues getting query to work at all. I admit I am a novice at using this sort of API and querying in general, so show some grace if I am doing this absolutely wrong.

By their own documentation, the makers of Denticon say you must query using a html request. When attempting to use 'request.get()' I get an error message that this method in not supported for the request when using it on a url for a specific query.

Here is some short documentation from their own website that could help fill some gaps:

- [Denticon API](https://dev-api.denticon.com/)
- [Denticon API Getting Started](https://dev-api.denticon.com/Home/GettingStarted)
- [Denticon Patient APIs](https://dev-api.denticon.com/Home/PatientV2Apis)

In my case I am trying to query a list of patients at a specific office/location. This is what I would think to try:

```
import requests

apiKey = {"API-AUTH-KEY":"AAC6DB7A-5A66-4EBC-B694-D6BCD99881CB",
          "API-VENDOR-KEY":"BCF756D4-DCE6-4F2B-BAAE-7679D87037A7",
          "PGID":"1"}

requests.get('https://dev-api.denticon.com/v2/api/Patient/AllPatients/', headers=apiKey)
```

(As a short disclaimer: these are practice api keys that Denticon provides. They do not allow you query any actual patient data, just to practice using the API)

At this point is where I get the "method not supported" response for request.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you cannot call the API using `requests.get`. Try to do it using `requests.post`.

```
import requests

apiKey = {"API-AUTH-KEY":"AAC6DB7A-5A66-4EBC-B694-D6BCD99881CB",
          "API-VENDOR-KEY":"BCF756D4-DCE6-4F2B-BAAE-7679D87037A7",
          "PGID":"1"}
json = {"OID":"","PAGEINDEX":"1"}          

requests.post('https://dev-api.denticon.com/v2/api/Patient/AllPatients/', headers=apiKey, json=json)
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks! for the sake of learning could you give a brief explanation of the difference between request.get and request.post?